# Prove or disprove that $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}, \lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Statement:** Prove or disprove that $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}, \lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor^2$.

**What I've tried:** Let $x$ be a particular but arbitrary chosen real number. By definition of floor, $$\exists m \in\mathbb{Z}: \lfloor x^2 \rfloor = m \le x^2 \lt m + 1$$
Let's take a square root of each part of the inequation.
$$\sqrt{m} \le \lvert x \rvert \lt \sqrt{m+1}$$
The inequation above defines flooring for $x$ relatively to $x^2$: $$\lfloor x \rfloor = \sqrt{m}$$

We need to prove that $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor^2$, but as was shown above, $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = m$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = \sqrt{m}$. Because $m = (\sqrt{m})^2$ this statement is true.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Consider $x=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Concerning your argument: $\sqrt{m}$ is in general not an integer...

Comment: Your proof fails when you write $ \lfloor x\rfloor = \sqrt{m} < |x| < \sqrt{m+1} $ the only sensible way to interpret this sentence is as containing the statement $\lfloor x\rfloor = \sqrt{m}$ which is simply not true in general

Comment: Also, it's not even true that $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor \geq \lfloor x \rfloor^2$ if we allow negative $x$.

Comment: Don't write Q.E.D when you are not even sure if it's correct.

Comment: @AlvinL the proof is wrong but I don't think its necessarily wrong to write "Q.E.D" when the writer of the proof is convinced that they are correct, if they intend it to, for example, mark the end of their attempted proof

Comment: Hi Vlad: $\lfloor (1.5)^2 \rfloor=\lfloor 2.25 \rfloor$ and $(\lfloor 1.5 \rfloor)^2=\lfloor 1 \rfloor$

Comment: Proof without word. Check the graph of both functions

Comment: @vlad really poofed the prove looks like.

Answer (score 4):

The mistake in the proof, as pointed out already in comments,
is the implicit assumption that $\sqrt m$ is an integer,
which you must believe in order to write $\lfloor x\rfloor = \sqrt m$.

This is also a clue to how to find counterexamples.

It is true (using the definition of the floor function) that
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R:\exists m\in\mathbb Z: \lfloor x^2 \rfloor = m \leq x^2 < m + 1.
$$
From this we can derive the true statement that
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R:\exists m\in\mathbb Z: \sqrt m \leq \lvert x \rvert < \sqrt{m+1}.
$$

However, this is not a description of taking the floor of $\lvert x \rvert$,
because in the definition of the floor function we require the two bounds to be consecutive integers.
We do not generally find that $\sqrt m$ is an integer when $m$ is an integer,
and we certainly do not generally find that $\sqrt m$ and $\sqrt{m+1}$ are consecutive integers; the only case in which they are consecutive integers is when $m = 0$.

In the case where $x$ is non-negative (so that $\lvert x\rvert = x$) and $m$ is a perfect square, it turns out to be true that
$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor^2$, because
then $\sqrt m$ is an integer and
$$ \sqrt m \leq \lvert x \rvert = x < \sqrt{m+1} \leq \sqrt m + 1 $$
shows that $\lfloor x \rfloor = \sqrt m$.

In the case where $x$ is non-negative and $m$ is not a perfect square, however, $m$ is positive but there is no integer between $\sqrt m$ and $\sqrt{m+1}$, so
$$
\lfloor \sqrt m\rfloor < \sqrt m \leq x < \sqrt{m+1} \leq \lfloor \sqrt m\rfloor + 1.
$$

By the definition of the floor function, this says
$\lfloor x\rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt m\rfloor$,
and therfore

$$
\lfloor x\rfloor^2 < (\sqrt m)^2 = m = \lfloor x^2\rfloor.
$$

So it is really easy to find counterexamples to the statement.
Just take any positive integer $k$ and choose a number $x$ such that
$\sqrt{k^2 + 1} \leq x < k+1$. Then
$ \lfloor x\rfloor^2 < \lfloor x^2\rfloor $.
If you take $k=1$, you find that any $x$ such that $\sqrt 2 \leq x < 2$
is a counterexample.

And what about negative non-integer values of $x$?
Then $x = \lfloor x\rfloor + \delta$, where $0 < \delta < 1$,
so

$$
\lfloor x\rfloor^2 = (x - \delta)^2 = x^2 + (\delta^2 - 2x \delta).
$$

But since $x$ is negative, $\delta^2 - 2x \delta$ is positive, and therefore

$$  \lfloor x^2\rfloor \leq x^2 < \lfloor x\rfloor^2. $$

So an even easier counter example is any negative number that is not an integer.

---

As a general strategy for problems like this, when you don't know if the statement is true, it pays to look for counterexamples first,
or at least concurrently with looking for a proof.
This statement is obviously true for integers, so try some non-integers.

If it turns out the statement is true after all, the failures of your attempted counterexamples may give some clues toward the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$$\exists x=  \left({\frac{7}{5}}\right) \in \mathbb{R} \colon \lfloor \left({\frac{7}{5}}\right)^2\rfloor \not = \lfloor  \left({\frac{7}{5}}\right)\rfloor^2$$